# Keep Laptop Connected to wifi when closed

Tags: wireless

Is there a way to keep my laptop connected to my home wifi when I close it? I remember being able to do this when I ran Windows, but I can't seem to find a setting for it? It would be helpful for longer downloads.

Comment: What do you mean by closed? Lid closed or sleeping (suspended)? If you want it to be when the lid is closed, there is an option for that in Power settings

Comment: Yes, I meant when lid closed. Do you mean, select "do nothing"

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for and open `Power` from the Dash
2. Change "When the lid is closed" to "Do nothing"